# Select all checkbox get selected by default when I don't have any records

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting problem by getting my select all button checked when there are no records.

Below is my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}"/>

 var getAllSelected= function () {
        var selectedItems = $scope.items.filter(function (item) {
            return item.selected;
        });
        return selectedItems.length === $scope.items.length;
    }

    var setAllSelected = function (value) {
        angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
            item.selected = value;
        });
    }

    $scope.selectAll = function (value) {
        if (value !== undefined) {
            return setAllSelected(value);
        } else {
            return getAllSelected();
        }
    }
```

So problem is below condition is getting true when I don't have records in my `$scope.items`:

```
return selectedItems.length === $scope.items.length;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code with below snippet:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])

.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {


$scope.value = false;
$scope.items = [{},{}];

 var getAllSelected= function () {
        var selectedItems = $scope.items.filter(function (item) {
            return item.selected;
        });
        return $scope.items.length != 0 && selectedItems.length === $scope.items.length;
    }

    var setAllSelected = function (value) {
      console.log(value);
        angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
            item.selected = value;
        });
    }

    $scope.selectAll = function (value) {
      console.log(value);
        if (value !== undefined) {
            return setAllSelected(value);
        } else {
            return getAllSelected();
        }
    }
  }]);
```

and

```
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}"/>
```

and it is working fine..

you can check here: https://plnkr.co/edit/oUjNQGI363SJPMeaWA6A?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple fix, just add a condition to make sure length is non-zero.

```
return $scope.items.length != 0 && selectedItems.length === $scope.items.length;
```

Comment: This worked but problem is i am unable to check my select all checkbox when there are no records.Atleast i should be able to check selectall checkbox in that case